# Problem with basic array filtering not working

Tags: google-apps-script

Array filtering not working as expected:

```
function getTest( myArray ) { 
  keySetTest = new Set('B-L002');

  var t2= myArray[2][0];
  var myResult = myArray.filter(dataRow =>keySetTest.has(dataRow[0]));   

  return myResult;
};
```

In the debugger it looks like this:

[image: Debug]

Why is myResult empty?
As can be seen from variable t2 it should contain at least the entry myArray[2],right?
I am using this logic almost identical in another context and it works fine.

Comment: There is a problem with your posting of code [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Where is `myArray` being declared?

Comment: @Cooper thank you for pointing out the problem with the format of the code, but I cant figure out what you see as problematic? I marked the code in the editor and hit the { }-button so it should be ok, or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your question of `Why is myResult empty?`, when I saw your script, it seems that `keySetTest = new Set('B-L002');` is required to be modified. Because I think that in your situation, when `keySetTest = new Set('B-L002');` is used, each character is split like `[ 'B', '-', 'L', '0', '2' ]`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
keySetTest = new Set('B-L002');
```

#### To:

```
var keySetTest = new Set(['B-L002']);
```

#### Testing:

When the modified script is tested using a sample value, it becomes as follows.

```js
var myArray = [["B-L002", "b1", "c1"], ["a2", "b2", "c2"], ["B-L002", "b3", "c3"]];
var keySetTest = new Set(['B-L002']);
var myResult = myArray.filter(dataRow => keySetTest.has(dataRow[0]));
console.log(myResult)
```

#### Note:

- In this sample, I guessed your sample value of `myArray`. When you use this modified script in your actual situation, when your unexpected result is obtained, please provide the sample value of `myArray` and your sample expected value. By this, I would like to confirm it.
- In your situation, the following modified script might be able to also obtain the same result.

  ```
    var myArray = [["B-L002", "b1", "c1"], ["a2", "b2", "c2"], ["B-L002", "b3", "c3"]];
    var myResult = myArray.filter(dataRow => dataRow[0] == "B-L002");
    console.log(myResult)
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: Your suggestion solved my problem. Thank you so much!